# Comparing 4 variables (integers) & find the biggest number

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

What would be the shortest & the easiest way to retrieve the variable with the largest value amongst 4 variables?

```
$a = 24224243243434
$b = 12312343432323
$c = 31231243434342
$d = 24343543432421
```

Comment: You want variable or value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Largest value:

```
PS C:\> ($a,$b,$c,$d|Measure-Object -Maximum).Maximum
31231243434342
```

Variable with the largest value:

```
PS C:\> Get-Variable -Name a,b,c,d | Sort-Object -Property Value | Select -Last 1 -ExpandProperty Name
c
```

Full variable name (with `$`):

```
PS C:\> '${0}' -f (Get-Variable -Name a,b,c,d | Sort-Object -Property Value | Select -Last 1 -ExpandProperty Name)
$c
```

Comment: thanks! mathias

but I want the variable return like $c , bcoz i want to use it further for some processing

Comment: @MartinWood Remove the `-ExpandProperty Name` part, then it returns the whole variable

Comment: Name   c                         

Value   31231243434342

Comment: No, that's what it prints in the console. It returned the variable object whose value you usually refer to by `$c`. If that's not what you're interested in, I'm not sure I understand. Would you rather like the string `"$c"`? The value?

Comment: when I do - 

$e = "a","b","c","d" |ForEach-Object {
    Get-Variable -Name $_
} | Sort-Object -Property Value | Select -Last 1

then, $e =$c is what i want